# Why weren't all usb ports type c /symmetric from the beginning?

Tags: usb

Did it really take them so long to think about a symmetric port?

Comment: Closed? Really? I actually thought it was quite a good question as many newer engineers forget how far we have come since 1996 when USB was first introduced. It was truly state of the art back then.

Comment: @Jon: It might be an interesting *discussion*, but unless somebody has some verifiable *facts*, it would be pure speculation, which is not what this site is about. Take it to chat. I recommend Googling "USB history" to get some perspective about what was driving the decisions in the 1994-98 timeframe when it was being developed. Symmetric connectors were simply "not a thing" at that time.

Answer (score 4):

Although @jsotola has a point (*never* underestimate the stupidity of users - they’re so creative!), the answer is more likely to be “complexity”.

USB was a proposed solution to a problem, and to succeed needed to be adopted as quickly and broadly as possible. To facilitate this, it above all needed to be *cheap*. This means that it needed simple circuitry, and as few proprietary chips as possible.

There are two sides to “symmetric” (pardon the pun):

- You can insert the connector either way around;
- Either side can provide or demand power.

The first adds complexity in wiring; the second adds complexity in power design. Both would have added to the cost, reducing the chances of widespread acceptance.

Now that USB has gained de facto ubiquity (even *Apple* have gone USB-C!) you can make these sort of user-experience modifications - and have no doubt whatsoever that they’re very complex and difficult! Getting it right has eluded many suppliers for a long time. Luckily, a number of chip manufacturers have solutions to help, so they’re not as expensive as they would have been at the beginning.